# Semantic UI - Get the Javascript working

Tags: semantic-ui

[image]I've just started with Semantic UI.
Take an example of their vertical menu below. This does render the UI, however it isn't functional. I do understand that there should be a javascript initialized for this. But where can I  find in the documentation about initialising the components.

```
<div class="ui secondary vertical pointing menu">
  <a class="item">
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="item active">
    Messages
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Friends
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: A menu does not use any javascript in SUI. Perhaps you're looking for [tabs](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#with-menus)

Answer (score 0):

Sarthak is right, the menu is component of the collection type and doesn't require any JS to correct work. However, examples in SUI's docs use some JS that handles switch of active class, here its code:

```
$(this)
  .addClass('active')
  .closest('.ui.menu')
  .find('.item')
  .not($(this))
  .removeClass('active')
```

[Full source](https://semantic-ui.com/javascript/menu.js)

Comment: If you check my edited post, I've uploaded a screenshot. The code snipped does not work on it's own. I'm quite sure it needs a js.